# Выравнивание custom-control bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, выравнивание

Подскажите пожалуйста как выравнять custom-control checkbox по центру (Bootstrap)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например с помощью [Flexbox-классов](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
  </div>
</div>
```